# Load Class if exists in cache

Tags: javascript

I'd like to build a "Module" System in JavaScript.

It should add all founded classes to an Array.

When I use the `import` function to import the class, it should check whether the class exists in the array, and is inherited from another class.

I found only the Performance API which shows me loaded resources, but not the Class, only a URL.

```
this.import("Navigation");
```

Scripts:

- `example-class.js`

  - `class Navigation {}`
- `example-2-class.js`

  - `class Footer {}`

At this time I use `eval` to "load" my Class but, it doesn't detect if the Class exists.

```
/**
 * Import a Class if File is loaded to Cache.
 * @param dependencyIO
 */
import(dependencyIO, callbackIO) {
    if (typeof window[dependencyIO] !== "undefined") {
        const objectIO = eval("new " + dependencyIO + "()");

        if (typeof objectIO !== "undefined") {
            guardianIO.print('LOAD', 'Using ' + dependencyIO + ' Class with Version ' + objectIO.versionIO + ' for MyTrioX Version ' + versionIO + ' (API: ' + nameIO + ' / BUILD: ' + buildIO + ')!', 'GREEN')

            if (callbackIO) {
                callbackIO(objectIO);
            }
            return objectIO;
        } else guardianIO.addError("Error, while loading Class " + dependencyIO);
    } else guardianIO.addError("Error, Class " + dependencyIO + " is not imported.");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `const objectIO = new window[dependencyIO];`, no eval needed, but on top of that, `import` is a reserved word for ES Modules, don't use it.

Comment: Okay, but the Class get not registered in the window array, on my Browser...

Comment: you cannot use `import` in JS, it's a reserve keyword for ESM. Change name, but also show the code in charge of registering, because it's not there.

Comment: Oh okay, yes but I don't register the Scripts. I like to use the HTML <script> function as Registry.

Comment: there's no `<script>` function as registry, unless you mean ESM. Otherwise you might use a `customElements` like registry to export module and retrieve these after. (search for custom-libraries in github or create your own registry). `import {thing} from "./module.js"` is an option though.